# Remove all entries in dictionary where value appears more than once

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and if a value appears more than once I want to delete all occurrences of the value and the respective keys.

Any help would be much appreciated.

For those curious my dictionary was as follows:

{'Monster 1': 'Modema', 'Monster 2': 'Aninige', 'Monster 3': 'Dolamisme', 'Monster 4': 'Malexo', 'Monster 5': 'Eludisnismu', 'Monster 6': 'Du-Minime', 'Monster 7': 'Anu', 'Monster 8': 'Mu', 'Monster 9': 'Aluligige', 'Monster 10': 'Asmismu', 'Monster 11': 'Aninige', 'Monster 12': 'Dolamisme', 'Monster 13': 'Esmusno', 'Monster 14': 'Asmismu'}

If any two monsters are in the same place (have the same value) then both the monsters and places must be destroyed.

Comment: What does your dictionary look like?  What do you have so far?

Comment: If your values are hashable, there's an easy solution using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Just keep another dictionary mapping value to key

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is a weird problem, since the order of the keys is not determined, hence running the program with the same dictionary twice, could result in *totally* different output. In the first run other keys can be deleted than in a second run.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem doesn't deleting **all** occurrences make this determinable?

Comment: @AChampion: yes, in that case it is deterministic :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Although no data is shared I think the question is quite clear, or what did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using pandas:** *just because you can :)*

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a':1,'b':1,'c':2, 'd':'cat','e':'cat','f':'cow'}

new_d = pd.DataFrame([d]).T.drop_duplicates(keep=False)[0].to_dict()
print(new_d)
```

Returns:

```
{'c': 2, 'f': 'cow'}
```

And using Collections Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'a':1,'b':1,'c':2, 'd':'cat','e':'cat','f':'cow'}

nondup = {k for k,v in Counter(d.values()).items() if v == 1}
new_d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v in nondup}
```